# Find CFG for given formal language

Tags: formal-languages, automata

I need help with this homework problem (Formal languages and Automata grad-level course).

Find a CFG for this language:
$$ \Sigma =\{0,1\}$$
$L$ are all the words $w\in\Sigma^*$ that in every prefix of $w$ there are at least as many $0$’s as there are $1$’s.

My attempt:
After much trial and error, I came up with this CFG:
$$ S\rightarrow 0S|01S|\epsilon|0$$
The idea I thought about is that for every $1$ added to S (they are added at the end of a prefix each time), a $0$ should be added too.
I don't have enough intuition to check my solution so I'm not sure at all that this is true. In general I am lacking intution and the right approach to these problems.

I would appriciate it if someone could show me the right way to approach this problem.

Thank a lot

Edit: This is obviously not true, it obviously doesn't cover all words in this language (only those who look something like this: $001010001010101....$. I have no idea how to make this cover all the language..

Comment: I don't think the answer is correct since you can't create 0011 with your CFG

Comment: @BinyaminR yeah i see that, edited the question

Answer (score 0):

I think:
$$S\to K1|0S|\epsilon$$
$$K\to KK1|0$$
will work. K represents you 'owe' a one.

I think showing that anything you get will be in the language, is pretty straight forward since you can't add a 1  without having a 0 behind it.

Comment: Could you explain please in principal why does this cover the whole language? (not a formal proof, just the idea)

Comment: Specifically why did you double the $K$?

Comment: @PhysicsPrincess I put the double K to allow longer sequences of ones. The logic is, that you are allowed to put as many ones as you want in a row, as long as you put enough zeros behind them